# Running through the elements in an iterator, then calling the methods?

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator

In one file i have this:

```
public DirectoryNode(String n, List<FileSystemNode> c) {
...
private List<FileSystemNode> nodes;
...
public Iterator<FileSystemNode> iterator() { return nodes.iterator(); }
...}
```

And in another file, I have this:

```
public class SizeVisitor implements FileSystemVisitor<Integer>
{...
    public Integer visitDirectory(DirectoryNode d){
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I, in the visitDirectory make a for loop, which will take the iterator for d, and go through all the elements, and then on each element call the method "getSize", which is implemented in FileSystemNode?
Thanks you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do something like this:

```
public Integer visitDirectory (DirectoryNode d) {
  for ( Iterator<FileSystemNode> iterator = d.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    FileSystemNode fsn = iterator.next();
    fsn.getSize();
  }
}
```

You can also make your `DirectoryNode` implement the [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface so you can use the foreach loop:

```
public Integer visitDirectory (DirectoryNode d) {
  for ( FileSystemNode fsn : d) {
    fsn.getSize();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just realized I made a mistake though - getSize isn't implemented in FileSystemNode, it's implemented in FileNode, which implements the interface FileSystemNode. Sorry about that. Do you have any ideas how to get around that problem?

Comment: Can you change the interface to also include the getSize() method? If not, you will need to check if the FileSystemNode is a FileNode (using `instanceof` and _then_ call getSize on a casted object: FileNode fn = (FileNode)fsn;

Answer (score 1):

Someting like this:

```
public Integer visitDirectory(DirectoryNode d){
 Iterator<FileSystemNode> i = d.iterator();
 while (i.hasNext()) {
   FileSystemNode fsn = i.next();
   fsn.getSize()
 }
}
```

If you implement the `Iterable` interface in `DirectoryNode` you can also use a for-each loop:

```
public Integer visitDirectory(DirectoryNode d){
  for (FileSystemNode fsn : d) {
    fsn.getSize()
  }
}
```